# Jordan curve theorem and connectedness.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

**Theorem** (Jordan Curve Theorem).
 If $J$ is homeomorphic to circle $S^1$ then a set $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash J$  has only two connected components and $J$ is their common boundary.

Now, with previous theorem, is it obvious that if $K$ is homeomorphic to closed disk $\overline{B}^2$, then a set $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash K$ is connected?

Comment: The quoted theorem isn't even true...

Comment: If you assume that the map $f$ is an embedding, then yes, you get what you want as a corollary of Jordan.

Comment: Yes, that theorem was hastily written.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Is it a trivial corollary without pitfalls? That result is in use when we prove *Invariance of domain theorem*.

Comment: Information such as "I want to use this to prove invariance of domain" should really be in the question, to avoid answers *using* invariance of domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e$ embeds the unit disk $D$ into the plane, with image $K$, then $e$ restricted to $S^1$ is also an embedding, to which Jordan applies. So $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus e[S^1]$ has two components, with common boundary $e[S^1]$. As $e[\operatorname{int}(D)]$ is connected, it's entirely contained into one, so must equal one of them. $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus e[D]$ is the other component.

Comment: But if we know that $\operatorname{int}(K)$ is connected and bounded domain, then isn't it trivial that it **must** be that "inner" domain stated in Jordan Curve Theorem? Now, when we cut off that inner domain and that boundary curve, what is left **must** be that connected "outer" domain

Comment: That's sort of what I said isn't it?

Comment: Sorry! Your answer is edited, and I just rushed with my comment. But again, why I can't find this "trivial" result in literature? This result is used in the proof for Invariance of domain theorem.

Comment: I am struggling to understand the last step. It is clear that $e[\operatorname{int} D]$ must be contained in one of the components, but the only easy way I can see to conclude that it covers that component relies on invariance of domain. Would you please explain?

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen: "Point $x$ being in a component" is an equivalence relation, so maybe it's clear by definition.

Comment: @Juho: by which definition? Not every connected set is a connected component. I think there has to be more to it than that.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen: But JCT says that plane is divided into two domains, and in Euclidean space domains are path-connected components. For components $G_x$, that contains $x$, and $G_y$, that contains $y$, we have $G_x \cap G_y = \varnothing $ or $G_x = G_y$.

Comment: @Juho: In open subspaces of a Euclidean space, a domain is a path-connected set, but not necessarily a path-connected component. It may be a proper subset of a path-connected component. More importantly, you seem to assume $e[\operatorname{int} D] = \operatorname{int} K$. As far as I can see this is a nontrivial fact, which can be used all by itself to show invariance of domain.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen: I'm no expert but isn't it so that when Euclidean space is locally path-connected, then a domain is actually path-connected component? So in JCT we are dealing with path-connected components and with that information we can conclude this equality in question.